# How to make cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback() more confident

Tags: python, opencv

I made a small test with `cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback()` to check how stable its result.
In my test I made a snapshot by the camera, cut two overlapping images with `(0,10)` distance between them.
I was expected `(0,10)` for each pixels, but the result is very different.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, img = cap.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)

left = gray[:-5, :]
right = gray[5:, :]

flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(left, right, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
flowx = flow[:,:,0]
flowy = flow[:,:,1]

cv2.imshow('flowx', flowx)
cv2.imshow('flowy', flowy)

print 'x.mean:', flowx.mean()
print 'x.max:', flowx.max()
print 'x.min:', flowx.min()

print 'y.mean:', flowy.mean()
print 'y.max:', flowy.max()
print 'y.min:', flowy.min()

cv2.waitKey()
```

**Result:**

```
x.mean: -0.00440598979749
x.max: 1.53141
x.min: -1.95973
y.mean: -2.53464987664
y.max: 0.844686
y.min: -5.43879
```

How can I make it to be closer to my expected `(0,10)` result ?